We are travelling to Phu Quoc from Perth Australia and have a 9 hour stop over in Kuala Lumpur. Do we need a visa to go out the airport?
We are travelling to Phu Quoc from Perth Australia, and have a 9 hour stop over in Kuala Lumpur. Do we need a visa to go out the airport ?

To get an answer, you need to state your citizenship. What has your own research on the topic revealed?

Assuming you are citizens of Australia, you do not need a visa for Malaysia for stays of up to 90 days.
You do, however, need to complete a digital arrival card called MDAC before arrival: https://imigresen-online.imi.gov.my/mdac/main
This is free and not a visa, it just replaces the old paper forms.
